# Extract and append unknown number of data.table columns under one new column name in R

Tags: r, data.table, apply, lapply, stringr

I have an R `data.table` created from splitting a string into paragraphs (using `stringr`) and then transposing, e.g. from something like:

`paras = dat[,transpose(str_extract_all(longstring, myregex))][, index := .I]`

where `longstring` is a multi-paragraph string and `regex` some regular expression used to split `longstring` into paragraphs (`index` is just a column I need for various joins later).

This creates a new data.table `paras` which has `index` and as many new columns (`V1`,`V2`,`V3`...) as there are paragraphs in the longest observation of `longstring` (in my case it goes to `V5`). Some observations of `longstring` have fewer paragraphs and then will have `NA` values in e.g. `V5`.

I want a new data.table which has only three columns: `index`, `V`, where `V` contains all of the non-NA `V1`, `V2`, `V3`... columns appended together, and `Vsource` which shows the "paragraph number".

This is easily done with:

```
newdat = rbind(
      paras[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V1, 1)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
      paras[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V2, 2)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
      paras[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V3, 3)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
      paras[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V4, 4)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
      paras[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V5, 5)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)]
      )
```

But the above is a really ugly way of doing this, and also requires me to hardcode the number of V variables. I would like a version which will work however many paragraphs are in `longstring`. I'm an R beginner and in my usual software (Stata) I could easily do this with a loop. But I can't get a loop to work for this problem in R, and anyway suspect there's some better vectorized way of doing, using something like `lapply` with `.SD`? But I'm still learning these methods.

PS: any good tutorials on using `lapply`, `sapply`, `apply` etc with data.table would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a `melt`. I'll demo with two simple sentences and split on `" "`, I think it should project on your real data.

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(longstring=c("this is a long sentence", "not as long"))
myregex <- " "
paras <- DT[, transpose(strsplit(longstring, myregex))][, index := .I]
paras
#        V1     V2     V3     V4       V5 index
#    <char> <char> <char> <char>   <char> <int>
# 1:   this     is      a   long sentence     1
# 2:    not     as   long   <NA>     <NA>     2

yourdat <- rbind(
  copy(paras)[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V1, 1)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
  copy(paras)[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V2, 2)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
  copy(paras)[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V3, 3)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
  copy(paras)[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V4, 4)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)],
  copy(paras)[,c('V', 'Vsource') := .(V5, 5)][!is.na(V),.(V,index, Vsource)]
)
yourdat
#           V index Vsource
#      <char> <int>   <num>
# 1:     this     1       1
# 2:      not     2       1
# 3:       is     1       2
# 4:       as     2       2
# 5:        a     1       3
# 6:     long     2       3
# 7:     long     1       4
# 8: sentence     1       5
```

(Note that I used `copy(paras)` here ... without it, the original `paras` had `V` and `Vsource` columns appended, which would disrupt the `melt` operation below.)

And the melt:

```r
melt(paras, "index", variable.name = "Vsource", value.name = "V", na.rm  =TRUE)
melted
#    index Vsource        V
#    <int>  <fctr>   <char>
# 1:     1      V1     this
# 2:     2      V1      not
# 3:     1      V2       is
# 4:     2      V2       as
# 5:     1      V3        a
# 6:     2      V3     long
# 7:     1      V4     long
# 8:     1      V5 sentence
```

You just need to string-ify and remove the leading `"V"` to get the same actual values.

```r
melted[, Vsource := as.integer(sub("^V", "", as.character(Vsource)))]
melted
#    index Vsource        V
#    <int>   <int>   <char>
# 1:     1       1     this
# 2:     2       1      not
# 3:     1       2       is
# 4:     2       2       as
# 5:     1       3        a
# 6:     2       3     long
# 7:     1       4     long
# 8:     1       5 sentence
```

(Assuming you really need an integer.)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I feel a bit silly for not recognising it's a melt/reshape but there you go!

One question: is there a reason you add the `[!is.na(V),]` chain when defining `melted` rather than using the `na.rm = TRUE` argument inside the `melt` function? I get identical results either way (I think).

Comment: @joshb nope, no reason, just started with what I did. `na.rm=TRUE` will do it equally well (perhaps better?).